# How can I check status bar background color in android (using espresso, uiautomator or ...)

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

How can I check status bar background color in android (using espresso, uiautomator or ...) ?

For example, I want to check that the status bar color is purple or not !!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

If you are using an ActivityRule, or something similar where you have access to the activity, great! You can access the statusBarColor easily, with `activityRule.activity.window.statusBarColor`. You can assert that the color matches your expected color just like in any unit test.

```
Assert.assertEquals(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.getColor(R.color.purple), activityRule.activity.window.statusBarColor)
```

**Option 2:**

If you're not using an ActivityRule, or the activity there is not the one you are testing (maybe you clicked a button that navigated you to a new activity and destroyed the original), you will probably need to create your own ViewAction.

Here's the one I created for testing in my flow. It gets the base context from a view, and unwraps it until it gets to the activity. Then it does the exact steps as above, for getting the statusBarColor from the activity. I prefer throwing PerformExceptions to directly making assertions in here, since the user can handle the exception a little more gracefully. Up to you!

The resolved hex colors serve no purpose, besides making the exceptions a little more readable.

```
fun withStatusBarColor(@ColorRes color: Int): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        private var resolvedColorHex = ""
        private var resolvedColor = 0

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return CoreMatchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.isEnabled(), ViewMatchers.isDisplayed())
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "checking status bar color"
        }

        override fun perform(controller: UiController?, view: View) {
            // get the base activity context to get the window
            var context = view.context
            while(context != null && context !is Activity && (context is ContextThemeWrapper || context is ContextWrapper)) {
                context = when (context) {
                    is ContextThemeWrapper -> context.baseContext
                    is ContextWrapper -> context.baseContext
                    else -> {
                        val exception = IllegalArgumentException("unexpected context type: ${context::class.java.simpleName}")
                        throw PerformException.Builder()
                            .withActionDescription(description)
                            .withViewDescription("context: ${context::class.java.simpleName}")
                            .withCause(exception).build()
                    }
                }
            }
            if(context is Activity) {
                resolvedColor = context.getColor(color)
                resolvedColorHex = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF and resolvedColor))
                val statusBarColor = context.window.statusBarColor
                val statusBarColorHex = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF and statusBarColor))
                if(resolvedColor != context.window.statusBarColor) {
                    val cause = "The expected status bar color: $resolvedColor ($resolvedColorHex) did not match the actual status bar color: $statusBarColor ($statusBarColorHex)"
                    throw PerformException.Builder()
                        .withActionDescription(description)
                        .withCause(AssertionError(cause))
                        .withViewDescription("status bar color: $statusBarColorHex")
                        .build()
                }
            } else {
                val contextClass = if(context != null) context::class.java.simpleName else null
                throw PerformException.Builder()
                    .withActionDescription(description)
                    .withCause(IllegalArgumentException("Context: $contextClass was not an Activity"))
                    .withViewDescription("context: $contextClass")
                    .build()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it, perform the action on any view in your activity:  `onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).perform(withStatusBarColor(R.color.purple))`